# Calculator form with custom formula editor (javascript)

Tags: javascript, forms, saas, calculator, gui-builder

Is there a software service permetting to create a form by adding inputs (textbox `a`, textbox `b`) and outputs (label `c`) where the `c` value would be an abstract formula coded by the user (javascript) from `a` and `b`?

say `function c(a, b){return a+b}`

Answer (score 0):

Several solutions available online:

- https://jscalc.io/ - basic interface, custom JS
- https://eu.jotform.com/build/222991988996081 - advanced GUI form builder, inclusing calculator and custom formula (graphic implementation)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).